# Pb when update / Listview, SQLite and click on a list element

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview, android-sqlite

I have a strange behavior on my listview.

My configuration :

[image]

My Problem:
When I click on an element, press back to return to the listview and repeat this action 5/6 times, I have a strange result in my View 2.
Sometimes the view is not filling with data… 
Data that comes from DB…

What is this ?
Update of DB and Listview which affect click on a element ?

Thanks for helping me

Comment: Can you provide some code? The problem can be how you pass your data to the View2 or how View2 control the content...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer

Some code if that can help :

```
// View1 to View2
Intent i1 =new Intent(this, View2.class);
i1.putExtra("IdExtraDB", XX);
this.startActivity(i1);


// View2
oncreate
this.IdExtraDB= Long.valueOf(this.getIntent().getExtras().get("IdExtraDB").toString());
if (this.IdExtraDB!= -1) {
    this.details = GetDetailsInDB();
}
```